# While saving data to mysql from my android app it removes spaces

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

suppose i have a field in which i will get full_name. so between firstname and lastname there should be a space. but when i enter like -- **Tom Cruise** ,,, it gives error ,, shows . but it takes **TomCruise** nicely. here is my code. i also dont have any trim function. so why i can not save white spaces.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:text="full name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**MainActivity.java**
i am just giving cruicial part.

```
private EditText editTextName;

 editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

String name = editTextName.getText().toString();

String urlSuffix = "?name="+name+"&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&email="+email;
```

i am sending to php site and then save it. works fine if i remove the space between words.

Comment: Why won't you use a direct SQL API to handle your DB connection?

Comment: i am new to android..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the space character to "%20".
name =  name.replace(" ","%20");

Answer (score 1):

```
private EditText editTextName;

editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

String name = editTextName.getText().toString();


String urlSuffix = "?name="+name+"&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&email="+email;

// Spaces are not allowed in urls, to represent it we use %20, add the below line to replace all spaces with "%20".

urlSuffix = urlSuffix.replace(" ", "%20");
```